# How to access folder inside MVC 3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've created a MVC 3 project using visual studio 2010 and IIS 7. After deploying my project to IIS I can successfully access the website using my domain address but I text gets displayed on the browser but not images, style sheets, etc... I right click one of the images on the browser to open on a new tab and the site redirects me to the log in page. so I was wondering if I need to give access to my Content/images folder for anonymous users to see? or maybe it has to do with IIS 7?

I am loading the images like follows

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image.gif")" width="413" height="220" alt="First Image" /></div>
```

This is my project web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
<add connectionString="Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX" name="ApplicationServices" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add connectionString="Server=XXXX;Database=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX" name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

 <appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
        <allow users=".\johnsmith" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <security>
        <authorization>
            <add accessType="Allow" users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </security>
</system.webServer>

<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Thanks, Y_Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `Content` folder is not *public* when you probably meant it to be. To give it access add a `web.config` file in the *Content* folder and [configure it properly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t). Or, re-configure your primary `web.config`.

---

> At run time, the authorization module iterates through the allow and
>   deny elements, starting at the most local configuration file, until
>   the authorization module finds the first access rule that fits a
>   particular user account. Then, the authorization module grants or
>   denies access to a URL resource depending on whether the first access
>   rule found is an allow or a deny rule. The default authorization rule
>   is . Thus, by default, access is allowed unless
>   configured otherwise.

Comment: In my we.config I have <add accessType="Allow" users="?" /> and <allow users="?" />, I though that could do the trick...

Comment: I added <allow users=".\johnsmith"/> which is an existing users and still no luck...

Comment: check to make sure there aren't any other web.config's with contradicting definitions ...

Comment: There was another web.config inside my Views folder but I removed it form the project and from windows and the error still persists.

Comment: Note: When I try to browse the images in IIS Manager I can see the images folder but when I expand it nothing shows; and when I click on Manage Folder->Browse I get a 403 error.

Comment: the `web.config` is added by the VS MVC template by default. i wouldn't remove it.

Comment: True, I was just pushing the solution.

Comment: try removing `<allow users=".\johnsmith" />` only keeping `<allow users="?" />`

Comment: Lol, turns out there was a web.config hiding in one of my sub-folders. It didn't even appeared in visual studio it was just in the folder :\. Thanks for the help!